# When writing to Firestore, how can I know that all triggered have finsihed?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Background: I am using Firestore as the main database for my (web) application. I also pre-render the data stored in there, which basically means that I collect all data needed for specific requests so I can later fetch them in a single read access, and I store that pre-rendered data in a separate Firestore collection.

When a user changes some data, I want to know when this background rendering is finished, so I can then show updated data. Until rendering is finished, I want to show a loading indicator ("spinner") so the user knows that what he is currently looking at is outdated data.

Until now, I planned to have the application write the changed data into the database and use a cloud funtion to propagate the changed data to the collection of pre-rendered data. This poses a problem because the writing application only knows when the original write access is finished, but not when the re-rendering is finished, so it doesn't know when to update its views. I can hook into the table of rendered views to get an update when the rendering finished, but that callback won't be notified if nothing visibly changes, so I still do not know when to remove the spinner.

My second idea was to have the renderer function publish to a pubsub topic, but this fails because if the user's requests happens to leave the original data unchanged, the onUpdate/renderer is not called, so nothing gets published on the pubsub and again the client does not know when to remove the spinner.

In both cases, I could theoretically first fetch the data and look if something changed, but I feel that this too easily introduces subtle bugs.

My final idea was to disallow direct writes to the database and have all write actions be performed through cloud functions instead, that is, more like a classical backend. These functions could then run the renderer and only send a response (or publish to a pubsub) when the renderer is finished. But this has two new problems: First, these functions have full write access to the whole database and I'm back to checking the user's permissions manually like in a classical backend, not being able to make use of Firestore's rules for permissions. Second, in this approach the renderer won't get before/after snapshots automatically like it would get for onUpdate, so I'm back to fetching each record before updating so the renderer knows what changed and won't re-render huge parts of the database that were not actually affected at all.

Ideally, what (I think) I need is either
(1) a way to know when a write access to the database has finished including the onUpdate trigger, or
(2) a way to have onUpdate called for a write access that didn't actually change the database (all updated fields were updated to the values they already contained).

Is there any way to do this in Firestore / cloud functions?

Comment: Why don’t you increment a counter in the rendered documents, in such a way a field always changes even if there is no change for the "meaningful" fields?

Comment: That sounds like it could work. I'd still like to wait for other answers to be sure I'm not missing a better way to solve my problem, but in case there aren't any, could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could increment a counter in the rendered documents, in such a way a field always changes even if there is no change for the "meaningful" fields

For that, the best is to use [`FieldValue.increment`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-increment).

Comment: I'd like to add that in the case of concurrent changes by another client, there is the additional problem that the client should only be notified after its change has been propagated. If a different change from a another client triggers the renderer first, "our" client updates and hides the spinner prematurely. AFAIK This isn't yet solved with an increment -- even if we include the counter value in the pubsub message, "our" client would not know what counter value to look for.

Comment: You should probably use a transaction then and maybe a flag with the userId. It all depends on the exact data model and how it is updated and read (copied from comments in the question for clarity).